# If a linear operator $T^n =0$, then $T-2I$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

So I know there are several duplicates to the question if a linear operator $T^n = 0$, then prove that $T-I$ is invertible. But it's set me wondering, what if it's $T-2I$? What if it's $T-aI$? I've tried approaching it along the same lines as $T-I$, but to no avail. That is, I haven't had any luck finding an inverse for the general case. Note: please don't use eigenvalues in your answers, I haven't yet studied them.

Comment: If $2=0$ in your ring, the problem is wrong. Are we supposed to assume the entries are in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ or something?

Comment: Presumably if eigenvalues have not been studied yet one can presume real or complex...

Answer (score 5):

If $T^n = 0$, then $T - aI$ will be invertible for all $a \ne 0$. This follows from the fact that $T - I$ is invertible for any such $T$. Notice that if $T^n = 0$, then
$$
\left( \frac{1}{a} T \right)^n = 0
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{1}{a} T - I
$$
is invertible, by the fact that we already know. Then multiplying by $a$,
$$
T - aI
$$
must also be invertible, since $a \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Consider the geometric series for $\dfrac{1}{z-a}$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose in your ring $u$ is a unit and you believe the theorem you referenced that "a nilpotent minus the identity is invertible".

Notice that $T/u$ is also nilpotent, and apply that theorem to get $\frac{T}{u} - I$ is invertible. But then $u(\frac{T}{u} - I)$ is invertible too.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lambda \neq 0$ and $S={1 \over \lambda} (I+({T \over \lambda}) + \cdots + ({T \over \lambda})^{n-1})$.
Note that $S(T-\lambda I) = I$